# Disputed Territories with PostGIS

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, spatial-query

I'm creating a game where someone can own some cities and belongs to a "tribe". That tribe have a "power" based on its member's individual power.

My goal is to show something like a contour that show the tribal-dominated territory and maybe consider the overlaping area as "disputed" (actualy I have no idea how to make the areas not overlap considering the tribe power to "push" the weak tribe area away). So I need to paint or take as a new polygon these disputed territories.

This is what I have until now using a OSM database as example just to test. Keep in mind that "highway" have nothing to do with this. It is just to take some points to test because I have not finished the tables yet:

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT ST_Collect(way) AS way
  FROM point where highway is not null group by highway
)
SELECT ST_Buffer(way,0.004) FROM j 
UNION ALL SELECT way FROM j;
```

[image]

Maybe I need to take some "power value" in the `WITH j AS` part and use it as parameter in `ST_Buffer(way,0.004)` replacing this hard coded 0.004 value so I can fine tune the tribe / city area and control its "influence" ... just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the very good Manisha's answer I have made some adjustments:

I moved the power points to the city table and then changed a litlle the final query because final_polygons are complaining something about GROUP BY blah blah...

The power factor must be reduced a little to 0.00001.

This is the final statement that gives both tribal and disputed areas:

```
WITH tribe_data AS (
  SELECT tribe_id, city_id
  FROM tribe_city_data
),
centroid_data AS (
  SELECT tribe_id, city_geom AS centroid_geom
  FROM city_table
  JOIN tribe_data ON city_table.id = tribe_data.city_id
),
power_data AS (
  SELECT tribe_id, SUM("power") AS total_power
  FROM city_table
  JOIN tribe_data ON city_table.id = tribe_data.city_id
  GROUP BY tribe_id
),
buffer_data AS (
  SELECT centroid_data.tribe_id, ST_Buffer(centroid_geom, total_power * 0.00001) AS buffer_geom
  FROM centroid_data
  JOIN power_data ON centroid_data.tribe_id = power_data.tribe_id
),
tribal_polygons AS (
  SELECT tribe_id, ST_Union(buffer_geom) AS polygon_geom
  FROM buffer_data
  GROUP BY tribe_id
),
disputed_polygons AS (
  SELECT a.tribe_id, ST_Intersection(a.polygon_geom, b.polygon_geom) AS disputed_geom
  FROM tribal_polygons a, tribal_polygons b
  WHERE a.tribe_id < b.tribe_id AND ST_Intersects(a.polygon_geom, b.polygon_geom)
)
select * from tribal_polygons
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM disputed_polygons
```

To take only one or other just change the final select to `select * from tribal_polygons` or `select * from disputed_polygons` and remove the UNION.

This is the table structures just for testing because the tribe table is actualy a join table and the tribe name must not be there. A real tribe table is missing:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.city_table
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    city_geom geometry NOT NULL,
    power integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    name character varying(200),
    CONSTRAINT city_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tribe_city_data
(
    tribe_id integer NOT NULL,
    city_id integer NOT NULL,
    tribe_name character varying(200)
)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

A good thing I found is the fact of separate cities keeps all the size power of it's tribe. I've found this very interesting.

[image]

... changing the points of "Ititioca" city gives much more power to all orange tribe!!

[image]

I am very satisfied !! Must decide what to do when a tribe overlaps another city with its influence power...

To find wich cities are overlaped by other tribes:

```
...
affected_cities AS (
  SELECT a.tribe_id, ST_Intersection(a.centroid_geom, b.disputed_geom) AS disputed_geom
  FROM centroid_data a, disputed_polygons b
  WHERE  ST_Intersects(a.centroid_geom, b.disputed_geom)
)
select * from disputed_polygons
union all select * from affected_cities
```